# SQL Server Data Tools business intelligence with express edition

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence

If I install in my PC :

1. SQL Server 2014 Express edition
2. SQL Server Data Tools Business Intelligence

Can I build SSIS packages?

I don't care about deploying, I just need a development environment.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can build and compile packages in SQL Server Data Tools with BI. They can only be deployed to SQL Server Standard or higher, which isn't an issues since you mention you just need a development environment.

Here are specific available features:

- Features by Edition of SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx
- Requirements for running SSIS in development projects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365338.aspx